# This selector should be .thisclass using Jquery

Tags: jquery

```
$("#maindiv").focusout(".thisclass", function(){
   $(this).addClass("warning");
})
```

I can't use `this` as an equivalent of `.thisclass`. In the above code, `this` refers to `#maindiv`. Please help me to make the selector `this` refer to `.thisclass`.

Comment: Does your `#maindiv` contains other element that have `class='thisclass'` ?

Comment: add html with this question ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`focusout()`](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/) doesn't take a selector as it's first argument.

It sounds like you may be confusing it with the delegated `on()` handler instead, which would require this logic:

```
$('#maindiv').on('focusout', '.thisclass', function() {
  $(this).addClass('warning');
});
```

Note that this requires the `.thisclass` elements to be descendants of `#maindiv`

Comment: Thanks for this. I just don't know about this delegete on().

Answer (score 0):

Reading your question, 2 scenarios comes to my mind :

1. You have a `#maindiv` in wich there is other elements, and you want to add class `.warning` to those whom has `calss='thisclass'`,
2. You want to add class `.warning` to the `#maindiv` if it has class `.thisclass`.

**For the first case :** you can do :

```
$("#maindiv").focusout(function(){
  $(".thisclass",this).addClass("warning");
});
```

**For the second case :** you can do :

```
$("#maindiv.thisclass").focusout(function(){
  $(this).addClass("warning");
});
```

Comment: I tried both codes. The first code adds a class to my target element. Unfortunately, the other element containing the same class is affected. The second code works well but for the newly appended element with the same class is not affected.